# Calling method of Another class from run() method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, servlet-listeners

I have created a scheduler which calls run method.

```
@WebListener
public class BaclkgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)  { 

        scheduler=Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SomeMinuteJob(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);      
     }
}
```

this calls to

```
public class SomeMinuteJob implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        System.out.print("Inside run method");
            ReadData obj= new ReadData();
            obj.readData();
            System.out.println("After reading data");
            }       

}
```

I have created `ReadData` class below.

```
public class ReadData
{
   public void readData()
   {
     System.out.println("I am inside readdata");
   }
}
```

So I have created object of `ReadData` inside the run() mehthod and I have called its method. But control is not coming to ReadData class. it is not printing the content inside readData() method. Even I created constructor and put some content but even though that is not printing. How can I resolve that?
Control is going inside run and it is printing `Inside run method`

Comment: Is this your real code? Where have you defined the `sout` method?

Comment: when I was writing then I wrote sout..I have clearly written full sysout method in code..let me edit the same

Comment: OK. The next thing to check is if you're running the code you think you're running. Stop all servers, delete all class files, and rebuild from scratch. Sometimes something "gets stuck" and keeps running the old version of your code.

Comment: I did @Joni .Even I created new project for the same and it is not working. in run() method it prints everything before I create object of another class. and after that it doenst print even what is written in run() method. I was thinking is there any issue with thread() and all? will join() ,notify() etc will work? though I tried but no help.

Comment: *"doenst print even what is written in run() method"* -  aha maybe an exception is thrown and silently swallowed? The code you post here cannot possibly throw an exception but maybe your real code is different? Put all code inside run in try-catch statement

Comment: @Joni Thank you Joni. you spotted correctly. Indeed there was exception in actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common problem with `ScheduledExecutorService` is that if the scheduled command throws an exception, the exception is silently swallowed. The code in the question does not seem to throw exceptions, but in more complex code it is difficult to avoid (for example unexpected NullPointerExceptions)

A quick fix is to put all of the Runnable.run method in a try-catch block:

```java
public class SomeMinuteJob implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.print("Inside run method");
            ReadData obj = new ReadData();
            obj.readData();
            System.out.println("After reading data");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly Jony. There was problem in my code.